# PHP PDO echo SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to echo out the `SELECT` statement that is in the PHP file.

It doesn't throw out an exception, however it doesn't throw the correct expected total from the query, it shows me 1 which is bizarre.

```
<?php require("config.php"); 
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total_record FROM  `markers` WHERE fishspecies =  'Bass'");
    echo $stmt ->execute(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$stmt->execute();` returns a truthy or falsey value.

It does **not** return rows from the database.

You need to use `fetch`, `fetchAll`, etc to get the values from the database.

Comment: what about echoing out the result?

Comment: @user2932546 read the DOCs :-)

Comment: Documentation is your friend.

Comment: @tadman as is pizza :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    require("config.php"); 
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total_record FROM  `markers` WHERE fishspecies =  'Bass'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $records = $stmt->fetchAll();

    //Specify the col_name
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
        echo $record['col_name'];
    }

    //Auto Print
    foreach($records as $col => $val)
    {
        echo "Column Name: $col - Value: $val <br/>";
    }

?>
```